# Paperclip with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using the papclip-ffmpeg gem to allow users to upload videos, i installed the gem and ran the quick start code in my user model.
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

```
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,

             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    def
             has_many :pins
             validates :name, presence: true
             has_attached_file :video, :styles => {
                    :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'flv' },
                    :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
                    }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]
    end
```

but this renders the error in the upload page to

```
Image There was an error processing the thumbnail for ob2-xvid-d0h-sample20140204-698-19dg2ms
```

Any ideas would be great thanks.

Comment: Have you tried another format for the thumbnail?

Comment: yes, tried .avi also, <div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <div class="box panel panel-default">
      <%= link_to image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium)), pin %>
      <%= link_to video_tag(pin.video.url(:medium)), pin>, this is my view

Comment: I mean your thumbnail format: `:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'png', ...`

Comment: yeah i've tried that same error

Comment: how about without the thumb option?

Comment: ok good, so no error, but, the view is not right, im using,<%= link_to video_tag(pin.video.url(:medium)), pin %> in index.html

Comment: how is the view "not right"?

Comment: oh sorry, its not rendering in the page, does the above look a little incomplete?, how would you suggest to display the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is when generating the thumbnail, do you have ImageMagick installed in your system?

Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

MacOSX

```
brew install imagemagick
```

To show your video, you can use:

```
<%= video_tag pin.video.url(:medium), :size => "320x240", :controls => true %>
```

Comment: Yup i have imagemagick installed, now it is this errorundefined method `video' for #<Pin:0x00000103405cf0>

Comment: For what I see in your model, video is a property of User, not Pin.

Comment: arg, would you be able to write up a demo on how you'd do it i'm missing something